# How does Lastpass recognize actual login?

Tags: authentication

We are currently working on simple school project using Codeigniter where we need login page. It would be very useful if Lastpass could recognise and save logins. We have several accounts with different roles and manual insert of login is pretty slow. So I was wondering what needs to be done and where in files (view, controller?) for Lastpass to work as it does on every website.

For example this is our login form:

```
    <?php echo form_open('login'); ?>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/> 
    </form>
```

Thanks for help.

(could not create new tag "Lastpass" due to low reputation)

Comment: Could you post your resolution as an actual answer below, and then accept it? Otherwise, this topic will never be closed and marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
<input type="text" id="password" name="password"/>
```

to

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
```